# Is there factor available to measure Replica shards latency in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In ES we know that when a document is submitted for the indexing first the data gets into primary and then the data get index replica shards. Is the writing operation to replica is immediate one or will there be any latency if there is any latency, is any parameter available to measure the latency?  And while writing data to replica due some reason if the write fails what will happen to the data in primary and will the data get replicate from primary again to replica.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At index time, a replica shard does the same amount of work as the primary shard. New documents are first indexed on the primary and then on any replicas. So unless the data is first completely written on the primary it won't start writing on to replica shard.

And while writing data to replica shard , if it fails you don't have to worry about primary & yes it will be re-written once you get the replica back

Comment: Thanks for answer Nishant, Is there any parameter available in ES to measure data write time gap between primary and replica shard.

Comment: I am not really sure if there is something like this exposed by ES. Probably not.